# Do all charged bodies behave like their charge is concentrated at the center of mass?

Tags: electrostatics

I know that a sphere behaves like it's charge is concentrated at the center. But do all charged bodies behave in the same way?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156789/electric-field-of-hollow-cylinder

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not. Imagine for instance two (equal) point charges $q$ separated by a distance $2d$, now you want to measure the potential along an axis perpendicular to the line connecting the charges, that bisects their separation. If you call $r$ the distance along such an axis then the potential is

$$
V(r) = \frac{2q}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{(r^2 + d^2)^{1/2}}.
$$

Compare this with the case in which you have the two charges placed at the origin

$$
V_0(r) = \frac{2q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}
$$

They are very different!

The fact that they are not equal is the reason behind the need of [Multipole Expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) to express the potential

Answer (score 0):

> I know that a sphere behaves like it's charge is concentrated at the
>   center.

Perhaps in the problems that you've seen so far, this is true but it isn't true in general.

At the undergraduate electrostatics level, there are canonical problems involving spheres with electric dipole (and higher) moments due to a *non-uniform* charge distribution.

For example, problem 3.35 from Griffith's "Introduction to Electrodynamics, 4th Edition" is

> A solid sphere, radius $R$, is centered at the origin.  The "northern"
>   hemisphere carries a uniform charge density $\rho_0$ and the
>   "southern" hemisphere a uniform charge density $-\rho_0$.  Find the
>   approximate electric field for points far from the sphere $(r \gg R)$.

Note that, by the symmetry of the setup, the *total* charge on the sphere is *zero* and so the *monopole* term of the multipole expansion vanishes leaving a leading *dipole* term far from the sphere.