# Water molecule $\text{H-O-H}$ angle in electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics, water, molecules

An image showing water molecule within a cylinder with positive charge on the inside and negative on the outside. To what extent will the $\text{H-O-H}$ angle adjust itself to the electrostatic force? Scaling this up to that the cylinder is not just a few hundred picometers, but a few micrometers, 10^5 times, is there still an effect?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE. For this kind of question we suggest that you add more details on what you know and what have you tried to do to solve such a question.

Comment: You suggest that. But, the question already has one upvote. So, there are other users who disagree with your opinion. The question is clear, I should have good enough knowledge for you to be able to convey the answer if you happen to know it, but not good enough to know certain myself as then I wouldn't ask.

Comment: Do you know what is the electric field inside a charged cylinder shell?

Comment: The question of whether a water molecule's bond angle will adjust to an electrostatic field is an interesting one!  But it's not particularly pertinent in the situation you've described;  can you see why?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Well no not really. Mauricio suggests the charge distribution I describe would not happen, but that assumes he knows the cause of it. There are real-world examples of such a charge distribution. And it was just an example.

Comment: If the hollow cylinder is "just an example" of a possible external charge configuration, it's not a particularly good one for one big reason.  See [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156789/electric-field-of-hollow-cylinder) for why.

Comment: It is a really good examples, as there are real world examples of exactly such configurations. But, yes it is just an example. The point is, a net positive charge acting on a water molecule in such a way, is the H-O-H angle "malleable" enough to adjust to that. The question is pretty easy, in text books the angle is very rigid, since it is a printed image, and question is mostly asks about how sensitive it is to other forces.

Comment: @user72 Your question could be interestingly improved by adding more detail. Is this a homework problem or just a curiosity? Do you want to model it? What are your assumptions? Do you know electrostatics?

Comment: The question is good. I mean, it is very easy, for anyone knowledgeable on how easily electrostatic charges affect H-O-H angle to answer it. To expect a complete profiling of whoever asks a question is a silly bias, it assumes you happen to be extra important, but this Q&A is lots of people. There were 2 upvotes. You yourself happen to dislike it, only, not a diffuse "we".

Comment: @user72 I am just trying to help, even a good question can alway be improved further. Here is a way to reach a solution based on a simple model: consider a charged infinite cylindrical shell, calculate the electric field inside the cylinder, deduce the force that it will exert on a test charge resting inside the cylinder.

Comment: Yes I could calculate on electrostatic repulsion. I do similar things in different fields in my every day life. But, an alternative, is to also ask, broadly. And people who are experts, and used to working with such things, and also understand the behaviour of H-O-H (as simply understanding the force magnitude itself does not answer that, which is what the question is), could then do what a Q&A is for, answer a question. If the possibility to ask questions and have them answered is removed because anyone can answer it themselves by calculations and study, then a Q&A site becomes meaningless.

Comment: Really what the question asks is about the magnitude of force required to affect the H-O-H angle. But that is also clear in it. So the force itself is not the point. This is why it just shows a big mass of "+".

Comment: Apart from the valid points raised about the electric field in your cylinder, why would you expect the bond angle to change? The shape of the neutral water molecule is determined by the electronic Born-Oppenheimer potential surface and for typical fields the Stark effect (interaction of dipole with external electric field) is orders of magnitude smaller than the electronic energies (so it does not change the shape). If you are interested in orientation of the molecule in an electric field, this depends also on the quantum state (high field seeker vs low field seeker).

Comment: First, there is perfect real world examples of the charge distribution in the image. I don't know what it is you think is invalid with it.

Why I expect charged particles to be affected by other charged particles, well, they are. That the force might not be sufficient, is what the question asks about. That someone might ask the question, is understandable. It is not completely a mystery, or very surprising. I'd be surprised if the angle is not affected, myself. In the image if it is taken literal the distance to the charges is just 100 picometer, but my question is mostly at larger distance.

Comment: There is a charge distribution in your picture, but no electric field (which is the gradient of the potential). A water molecule is neutral and not charged so it is only affected by an electric field via it's effective dipole moment and polarizability. Strictly speaking there is no field in your picture so no interaction. Apart from the physics, you come across as rather defensive while all we are trying to do is to help you understand the problem you asked.

Comment: there is repulsion between the charges. it is similar to if you have a dipole, like water, and orient + and +, it does not want to do that. I am not more defensive than anyone else, really. the good thing is people can have different opinions, you can have the belief that I am defensive, someone else might not, etc.

Comment: this will likely just go into unresolved arguing and then be "moved to chat", but, of course there is electrostatic repulsion/attraction. I mean, the claim that it isn't, that has gotten at least 2-3 followers in this thread, is false. an example is 3 dipole molecules, and orient them like in image, they do affect one another. then if the effect will be strong enough to affect H-O-H angle is other issue, but to reject electrostatic force is not a good start.

Comment: To address (and "not be defensive") the claim from three people, it is like claiming there would be no force here, https://i.imgur.com/tzArD1C.png. It is false. Of course the scenario in the image is very unrealistic since the two dipoles replacing the cylinder have to be "locked in place", but of course there is an effect. And politely replying like this just ends up wasting space and then I get labelled for "discussing", because I took the time to respond to a false claim. And that's supposed to be scientific.

Comment: Might I suggest that you edit the question to ask "what is the response of a water molecule's bond angle to an external electric field?", and omit the specific example of it being inside a cylinder?  This would get more directly at the question you're trying to ask (which is quite interesting, I think!) and avoid the distraction of why there isn't an electric field inside a uniformly charged cylindrical shell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, for long enough distances/small fields the water molecule is neutral, better modeled as a dipole but does not really influence the angle. For strong fields there might be an influence and that it is worth investigating. The answer is complicated as it will depend on experimental feedback, quantum mechanics, contact forces and, most importantly, solving the problem for different geometries.

However in your image above you have chosen a very symmetric case. The axial symmetry of the problem allows to calculate the electric field very easily. Mike S already pointed to the answer: [Electric Field of Hollow Cylinder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156789/electric-field-of-hollow-cylinder) . I will limit myself to provide you the main result that concerns you.

Let us say that the angle of water molecule when the cylinder is not charged is $\theta_0$. When is charged it becomes $\theta_0+\Delta\theta(d)$, where $d$ is the distance. When you solve for the electric field in the cylinder, you will find that the $\Delta\theta(1\;\mathrm{pm})=\Delta\theta(1\;\mu\mathrm{m})$ (strict equality).

In conclusion, for the geometry given, the angle does not change with distance, the rest is up to you to see why.